# How is this expression involving post- increment operator evaluated?

Tags: c, post-increment, comma-operator

```
main()
{
 int x = 0;
 int y;
 y = (x++, x++);
 printf("%d", y);
}
```

Since the precedence of `,` operator is R-to-L, I expected the o/p to be 0, but on compiling the code is giving o/p as 1.

Comment: I don't understand you logic. How the R-to-L evaluation order (which is incorrect) is implying the `0` result you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a comma operator, so this is reasonably well defined.  The subexpression

```
x++, x++
```

on the right-hand side means "add one to `x` and return `x`'s old value, then add 1 to `x` and return `x`'s old value."  But the first "return value" gets thrown away, and the second part is what gets assigned to `y`, namely `x`'s value after the first "add 1 to `x`" part, namely 1.

The comma operator always throws away the value computed by its left-hand side, and returns the value computed by its right-hand side.

Breaking it up even more explicitly, we have

```
y = (x++, x++);

     x++,            /* add 1 to x, giving 1, store 1 in x, return 0 (ignored) */
          x++        /* add 1 to x, giving 2, store 2 in x, return 1 */
y = (        );      /* so the 1 gets stored in y */
```

But notice that this has been well-defined *only* because of the sequence point that the comma operator gives you.  For the comma operator and just one or two others, it's guaranteed that everything on the left-hand side (the computation of `x + 1` *and* the store of this new value back into `x`) happen first, before anything on the right-hand side happens.  But this is *not* true of most operators in C.

In particular, if we were to write the similar-looking expression

```
y = (x++ + x++);    /* WRONG, undefined */
```

there would be no sequence point, so there would be nothing to tell us what order the increments of `x` happened in, what values would get added together, what value would be assigned to `y`.  See the canonical question [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior/51876456#51876456) for more on this kind of undefined expression.

Oh, and going back to your original question, you said

> Since the precedence of , operator is R-to-L, I expected...

But this is wrong on several counts.

- In this context, words like "right" and "left" generally refer to associativity, not precedence.
- The associativity of the comma operator is left-to-right, not right-to-left.
- The precedence of the comma operator is quite low (not that this matters).
- Precedence and associativity don't actually help you understand evaluation-order puzzles like this at all.

On that last point: I'm not going to write another long essay on this topic here now (see [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior/51876456#51876456)), but if you were trying to figure out the behavior of the undefined expression

```
y = x-- - x--;
```

by saying "okay, the associativity of the `-` operator is left-to-right, so we know that the left-hand `x--` will get evaluated first, then the right-hand one", that would be a wrong conclusion, which would not lead to a correct prediction of the behavior of the expression.

Comment: Very well done. The language of the standard speaks in terms of the result of the postfix ++ operator being the value of the operand with the increment being applied as a "side effect", see [6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4p2)